# Starting up too much time and high cache storing android

Tags: android, caching, startup

I am working on an Android App and I have just realised that it takes too much time to launch the app the first time and it seems to be because it stores a lot of information on the cache (nearly 16 Mb)

Thing is, I am not working with images and it's not such a complex app. What could be the problem?

-The first time you launch the app, it takes 20 sec to open. (And sets the cache on 16 Mb)

-After that it takes 4 sec to open (still a lot)

-If I clear the cache, and open the app once more time, it takes another 20 sec to open (And then the cache is again 16 Mb)

And the main activity is just a layout with 2 buttons and that's it.

EDIT: this is the code of the main activity.

```
    package pablopicazo.consejoswifi.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import pablopicazo.consejoswifi.R;
import pablopicazo.consejoswifi.activities.test.TestDescription;
import pablopicazo.consejoswifi.activities.test.TestResults;
import pablopicazo.consejoswifi.activities.tools.Tools;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Declare layout elements
        ImageView testwifiButon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_testwifi);
        ImageView toolsButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_tools);


        //Buttons listeners
        testwifiButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //If there's a test made previously, show the results. Otherwise, starts new test
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("testAnswers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (sharedPref.getString("testResults", "").equals("")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, TestDescription.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, TestResults.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        toolsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Tools.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

THIS ARE THE CACHE FILES THAT MAKES A 13MB CACHE SIZE
[See cache files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl0cI.png)

Comment: Are you testing the app in a real device or an emulator?

Comment: In a real device

Answer (score 0):

- Start tasks after the launch.
- Your code looks to be loading cache into the main thread.
- Load partially with loadings so app doesnt gets frezze.

Comment: It doesn't start any task in the lunch. I have also used "manageSpaceActivity" in other activity, but it remains the same.
And what do you mean by load partially?

Comment: Yes, then you should do time consuming tasks in AsyncTasks or Threads.

Comment: Loading partially would be breaking loading data importants first, then show some loadings place holders in your app while other data loads in background

Comment: Thing is, I don't understand why this cache is being loaded in the main Activity. There's nothing there more than adding 2 listeners to two buttons, that's it.
No tasks

Comment: You'll have to add code of your Activity so we can analyse it

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Are you sure its that Activity that does take long to start? Or pressing a button on it. Theres nothing wrong, except if you did crazy things on activity_main.xml

Comment: I know, that's why I come here. It's when opening for the first time as described. Also, if I choose any other activity it happens the same.

Comment: Have you a Custom Application class? if it takes long also any Activity will too

Comment: No, is the AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I mean Application, not Activity.

Comment: I have added the files that makes the cache big